# C# Read a row in a file

Tags: c#, file

Given text file which contains the registration data like a database:

```
[ID]    [Uname] [PW]    [Email] 
0       Aron    asd     asd@mail.com
1       Aron2   asdd    asd@mail.com
```

I have the username and the password input.
How would i read only that line in this text file where my uname.Text and password.Text are given?

Comment: Is this a local test? Because if something like this is used in any production environment, then having a text-file with flat-text passwords is pretty bad..

Comment: Yes this is a local test.And also i want to try making a local database which  will be integrated in the executable file. :)

Comment: Parse first line of file to check for the column names then retrieve each line and seperate it on the white-space characters then match against your login input OR a regex

Comment: @Aaron Ah good that it's just a test, you scared me there. As for the actual question: you can use `File.ReadLines("\path\to\your\file.txt");` to get a list of strings containing each line of the file. How to convert each of the lines into separated strings depends on a few things. Are the four columns shown the only four, and does none of them contain any whitespaces? If so, you could use a white-space split on the line-strings to separate them.

Comment: It looks like the columns have fixed positions. String.Substring can be used to extract the different parts from the lines. String.IndexOf can be used to find the [ characters on the first line.

Comment: Check out string.Split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with all the comments above. With the hypothesis that the file is not huge, you can simply load it all in memory and work on it:

```
//Load your files in a list of strings
IList<string> lines = File.ReadLines("\path\to\your\file.txt");

//Filter the list with only the pattern you want
var pattern = username + "[ ]{1,}" + password;
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
IList<string> results = lines.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).ToList();
```

Here's a [.NET fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GcRvQi) that shows this.

Comment: Wow,I didn't expected it is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var username = "Aron2";
var password = "asdd";
List<string> matchedValues; // Contains field values of matched line.
var lines = File.ReadLines("input.txt");

foreach (string l in lines)
{
    var values = l.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
 
    if (values.Contains(username) && values.Contains(password))
    {
        matchedValues = values;
        break; // Matching line found. No need to loop further.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!Maybe this works too,but  I solved my problem as Kevin wrote. :))

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have this problem too, this is my solve:

```
int check=0;
if (txt_uname.Text != "")
            {
                check = 0;
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
                string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split('\t');
                string newline;
                while ((newline=file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] values = newline.Split('\t');
                    if (check== 0){
                        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (txt_uname.Text == values[i] && txt_pw.Text == values[i + 1])
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("User found");
                                check= 1;
                                break;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("User isn't exists");

                            }
                        }


                    }

                }
```